# Can a programming language do anthing outside of what the OS provides?

Tags: programming-languages

I am trying to gain a more holistic, general, and high-level understanding of programs and programming languages.

I would like to understand how they actually function. I understand at the lowest level is machine code which is 0 and 1s. Then you have assembly. Then you have another high level language where every instruction/function/method/call/routine whatever you want to call it maps to some instruction or group of instructions in assembly right? The higher level language cannot provide or do anything outside of what the lower level language assembly provides correct?

Similarly, since all code runs on an OS, that code can only do things that the OS provides. It is impossible for the code to do anything outside of what the OS actually provides correct?

Comment: My OS does not provide specifically for a Scrabble game, and yet I was able to use a programming language to write code to implement a Scrabble game.  Clearly it is possible to do something outside of what the OS provides.   This is a somewhat tongue-in-cheek way to say it, but I think your question needs to specify what it means by "the OS provides" and "outside" of that.  From my point of view, what the OS provides is the ability for me to write and run whatever programs I want to write, albeit within some limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer has an instruction set, machine code, which defines what can be done on the computer.  Assembly code is essentially a more convenient representation of that, so assembly code can do anything the machine can do.  A higher-level programming language has to run on the machine, so it can't do anything the machine can't do, though it may well be able to express it more conveniently (e.g. `print "foo"` rather than several dozen machine-code instructions).  It is a matter of implementation choice whether the compiler for that programming language generates machine code directly, or assembly code, or any other form that might need further processing.

This brings us to the question of whether it's possible for a program (regardless of what it's written in) to do something the OS does not explicitly provide for.  I find this an odd way to express it, since the point of writing a program is to give you some capability that you didn't have before, so in some sense you only write programs for things the OS does not explicitly provide you with.  The problem lies in defining what the OS "provides".  If it's a general-purpose OS, then its designers likely intend to "provide" the ability for you to write a wide range of programs.  The OS may choose to provide some convenient feature (say, the ability to create files) but if it did not provide such a feature, you could perhaps do it yourself, given suitable motivation (and, for the file creation example, the ability to do disk I/O - possibly requiring you to write a disk driver too).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think you understand what I'm trying to get at. Please help me refine my question. I am trying to understand the relationship between higher level languages and the OS as you described. I don't really understand the limits as you put it. One example is networking. The OS provides functions for you to use it's IP stack. If it didn't, how else would this be used? Doesn't an OS have to provide something? Maybe it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe another way to express my question is what is the relationship between what a higher level language is capable of and what an OS provides?

Comment: With specific regard to the networking question: I've used OSes that don't provide any networking.  I have then *written* networking software for such OSes (which my employer then sold; that was the point).  All that was needed from the OS was the ability to add a device driver.  So there's a fuzzy boundary between what the OS provides and what you can do; what you can do, in this case, is determined mostly by how much effort you're willing to put into it.   (And no sane app programmer these days would be prepared to provide their own TCP/IP implementation).

Comment: Your choice of programming language may well restrict the kinds of programs you can write, but that's because the programming language itself was designed with certain kinds of programming in mind.

Comment: If the OS didn't provide networking, what did you write your code in? Were you writing it in Assembly which provided for the networking and therefore you were just expressing it in a higher level language as you put it to make it more convenient?

Comment: Various languages, depending on the particular example we're talking about. Some assembly.  Some higher-level, about the same as C (Bliss, to be exact).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, even though the OS did not "provide" anything specifically for networking, the instruction set did. So really the only limiting factor to what a program can do is what lower level instructions their functions map to correct?

Comment: I'd say that a given OS (a) makes some things easy by providing explicit facilities, (b) makes some things impossible by intentionally preventing them, and (c) is neutral on the rest, reducing it to a cost/benefit tradeoff.

Comment: What is this particular topic called formally as it relates to understanding the entire code stack so I can do more in depth reading on it?

Comment: I don't know that there is a formal name for it, or even that it's "a topic".  Indeed, I find the layering approach here to be artificial (as you can probably tell from my comments thus far).  As to the OS part, that is surely the realm of comparative study of OS capabilities (I just made that phrase up).   I don't mean to be overly negative - good luck with your quest!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to gain a more holistic, general, and high-level
>   understanding of programs and programming languages.
>
> I would like to understand how they actually function.

I recommend working through the understanding of modern hardware to get good performance and energy efficiency with the following as example:
With `subword parallelism` to improve `matrix multiply` by a factor of 4. 
Doubling the performance by unrolling the loop to demonstrate the value of `instruction level parallelism`. 
Doubling performance again by optimizing for caches using
`blocking`. 
Finally, A speedup of 14 from 16 processors by using `thread-level parallelism`. 
All four optimizations in total add just 24 lines of C code to a matrix multiply example you find in

> Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware Software Interface (5th ed.)

or similar books.

To make a point, it really is worth it to dig deeper than just "learning python" even if it is a good start. So understanding low level really effects high level programming in many ways and thats what you are after according to your question.

There is actually not just Assembly - there are hardware description languages as VHDL thats handled in this topic f.e.: 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132611/whats-the-motivation-in-using-verilog-or-vhdl-over-c